# How can I replace column values conditionally in python?

Tags: python-2.7, replace

My intention was to replace strings in the dataframe Step column 'description' containing "Final " in this column but my code doesn't seem to be working as intended. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
for x in Step['description']:
    if x[:5]=='Final':
        x.replace('Final','')
```

Comment: You can use the `apply` method on the description column: `f = lambda x: x.replace('Final', '') if 'Final' in x and x.index('Final') == 0 else x` `Step['description'].apply(f)`

Comment: Kevin, this works thank you

Comment: @Analysa Kevin's answer is slow, use this: `df['description']  = df['description'].str.replace('Final', '')
`

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
df['description'].replace(['Final'], ' ')
```